# Java OOP Changing the position of 2d matrix?

Tags: java, oop, matrix, 2d

If I have a matrix such as 3x4 with values of

1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 1 2 3

and lets say the user wanted to rotate a column: 
Enter column no = 2. Result will be like:

1 `6` 3 4 
5 `1` 7 8 
9 `2` 2 3

and after that I want to save this matrix so that I can rotate its row with another method: 
Enter rows no = 2; then result will be:

1 6 3 4 
`1 7 8 5` 
9 2 2 3

```
public class Matrix
{
    int row;
    int column;

    int[][] arrays = new int[row][column];

    public Matrix(int row, int column)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.arrays = new int [row][column];
    }

    public int getRow()
    {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row)
    {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getColumn()
    {
        return column;
    }

    public void setColumn(int column)
    {
        this.Column = column;
    }

    public int getArrays()
    {
        return arrays[row][column];
    }

    public void setArray(int row, int column)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    public void show()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.column; j++)
            {
                if(count < 9)
                {
                    count += 1;
                    System.out.print(count);
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                    count += 1;
                    System.out.print(count);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public void rotateColumn(int column)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.column; j++)
            {
                if(j == this.column - 1)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very new to Java OOP and it will be really helpful if someone can help me to clarify and guide my next steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that your matrix is not [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 1, 2, 3]] but this [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I propose a few changes to the code provided:

1. You had `arrays`, which is good, but you didn't use it / fill it (which is what *@tumisma* meant with his comment.) In the code below it is used.
2. private fields instead of package-private (no modifier)
3. You don't need setters for the rows/columns, only a constructor
4. I would separate the fill and show methods
5. You can use `count++;` which is a shorter way for `count += 1;` / `count = count + 1;`
6. When you reset the count to 1, you can do that directly (`count = 1;`) instead of `count = 0; count += 1;`
7. You don't need to put anything in the `System.out.println();` for an empty line / enter.

This results in the new code:

```
public class Matrix
{
    private int amountOfRows;
    private int amountOfColumns;
    private int[][] matrixArray;

    public Matrix(int amountOfRows, int amountOfColumns)
    {
        this.amountOfRows = amountOfRows;
        this.amountOfColumns = amountOfColumns;
        matrixArray = new int[amountOfRows][amountOfColumns];

        fillMatrixArray();
    }

    private void fillMatrixArray()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int r = 0; r < amountOfRows; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < amountOfColumns; c++)
            {
                if(count < 9)
                {
                    count++;
                    matrixArray[r][c] = count;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If we reached 9, we reset back to 1
                    count = 1;
                    matrixArray[r][c] = count;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int[][] getMatrixArray()
    {
        return matrixArray;
    }

    public int getAmountOfRows()
    {
        return this.amountOfRows;
    }

    public int getAmountOfColumns()
    {
        return this.amountOfColumns;
    }

    public void show()
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < amountOfRows; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < amountOfColumns; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrixArray[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // TODO: rotateColumn(int columnNr)

    // TODO: rotateRow(int rowNr)
}
```

So, then now the main part of your question: How to implement the rotate rows/columns methods. I first wanted to do it directly, but I was having a lot of trouble doing so. Instead, I create a temporary 1D-array of the selected column; then rotate those values around once counterclockwise; and then put them back into the matrix:

```
public void rotateColumn(final int columnNr)
{
    int columnIndex = columnNr - 1;

    // Values of the selected column in a temporary 1D-array
    int[] currentOrder = new int[amountOfRows];
    for (int r = 0; r < amountOfRows; r++)
    {
        currentOrder[r] = matrixArray[r][columnIndex];
    }

    // Rotate the values once counterclockwise
    int[] newOrder = new int[amountOfRows];
    for (int r = 0; r < amountOfRows; r++)
    {
        newOrder[r] = r == amountOfRows - 1
            ? currentOrder[0]
            : currentOrder[r + 1];

        // NOTE: This above is a shorter way for this:
        //if (r == amountOfRows - 1)
        //{
        //    newOrder[r] = currentOrder[0]
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    newOrder[r] = currentOrder[r + 1]
        //}
    }

    // Replace the column in the matrix with this new ordered column
    for (int r = 0; r < amountOfRows; r++)
    {
        matrixArray[r][columnIndex] = newOrder[r];
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(3, 4);
    matrix.show();

    matrix.rotateColumn(2);
    matrix.show();
}
```

Output:

```
1234
5678
9123

1634
5178
9223
```

I'll leave the implementation of the `rotateRow`-method to you. I'm sure there is a more efficient way / direct way than putting the column in a separate array, rotate it, and put it back, but I was unable to find it so I used this work-around instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the edit@Kevin , could you provide some advice for me in order to actually create my own solution to this kind of problem? Do you use trial and error or how did you break down the problem to find the solution you wrote. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry if I spoiled too much. My first approach was trying to rotate the column inside the existing 2D array itself. This didn't really worked out too well, since I either had something completely wrong (like the entire column became `2 2 2`, or everything was correct except for a last number). I also tried doing a backwards for-loop in this approach (`for (int r = amountOfRows - 1; r >= 0; r--)`), but that also didn't work. Then I came up with the isolation of the column, rotate that, and re-insert it, which was pretty easy, although not as efficient as I wanted (considering the 3 for-loops).

Comment: To add to my comment above, yes, I was kinda trial-and-error-ing at first, but since it took a bit long I looked for a less ideal, but easier to implement approach, which is what I show in my answer. It does 3 for-loops in just the `rotateColumn`-method, so I'm not really satisfied with the solution, and perhaps someone else has a performance-wise better approach for your problem. But it works, and with the little things being done inside the loops and the small grid (< 1000), it barely matters if you loop 3 or 9 times performance-wise anyway.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the guide. 
Have a nice day :) @Kevin